# Attribute of a Token, stored in an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, logic

Im trying to search a specific attribute of a token, stored in an arraylist.
i want to know whether there is a "+", and if so i want to know where. if not, i want to know whether there is a "-" and so on...

```
public BaumMitToken(ArrayList<Token> tokenList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++){
        if(tokenList.get(i).getContent().equals("+")){
            splitPoint = i;
            content = tokenList.get(i);
            break;
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(i).getContent().equals("-")){
            splitPoint = i;
            content = tokenList.get(i);
            break;
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(i).getContent().equals("*")){
            splitPoint = i;
            content = tokenList.get(i);
            break;
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(i).getContent().equals("/")){
            splitPoint = i;
            content = tokenList.get(i);
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

what do i have to do, when i want to find out, whether any token contains "+", THEN "-", THEN "*" and after that "/"? like this, i only get the first of any of these strings.

Comment: So that is 4 tokens in a row, the first contains `+` the next `-` the next `*` and the next `/`?

Comment: because you break the loop after you found one of your attributes. so you cant find  more than one token.

Comment: its a term like 1*36+9-1. what do i have to do then? if i dont break, i find the last one in the list.

Comment: What is this for? Wouldn't it be better to just iterate over the tokens and construct the tree on the go? Looping through the entire list each time you're looking for a token seems inperformant.

Comment: store it in a list and dont break after you found some right token.

Comment: im going to build a ast. so i have to search for + and - first of all, so i can realize point before line

Comment: Hmm, I'm no expert in that field but I feel there's a better algorithm that builds the tree in one go. Besides that you could do what MT already stated, collect the indices for the tokens into a list. You might try something like `Map<String, List<Integer>>` (or better a Google Guava `ListMultimap<String, Integer>`) with the tokens being the keys and the list of indices for each token being the values. You'd then just look up the tokens in that map.